# Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space. Set (the default bounded metric) $\bar d : M \times M \to R$ by $\bar d(x, y) =$min {$d(x, y), 1$}, Show that:...

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces, equivalence-relations

> Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space. Set (the default bounded metric) $\bar d : M \times M \to R$ by $\bar d(x, y) =$min {$d(x, y), 1$}. Show that:

> a) $\bar d$ is a metric in $M$.

> b) $d$ and $\bar d$ are equivalent.

> c) Every $A \subset M$ is bounded on $(M, \bar d)$, but not necessarily bounded on $(M, d)$.

a) To be a metric we need $\bar d(x,y)\ge 0$; $d(x,x) = 0$ if and only if $x=y$; $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$; $d(x,z) \le d(z,y)+d(y,x)$

$\bar d =$ min {$d(x, y), 1$} and $d$ is metric so $d(x,y) \gt 0$ and min {$d(x, y), 1$} $\ge 0$.

$\bar d (x,x)=$ min{0,1} $= 0$.

$\bar d (x,y)=$ min{$\vert x-y \vert$, 1}=min{$\vert y-x \vert$, 1}=min{$\vert x-y \vert$, 1} = $\bar d (y,x)$.

$\bar d(x,z) \le \bar d(z,y)+\bar d(y,x) = \vert x-z \vert \le \vert z-y \vert + \vert y-x \vert = \vert x-z \vert \le \vert z-x \vert$.

c)$\bar d(x, y) =$min {$d(x, y), 1$} and we know that $ d(x,y) \ge 0$ so $\bar d(x, y) =$min {$0, 1$} therefore $\bar d$ is limited by $0$ and 1.

On the other hand $d(x,y)$ can take any value greater than $0$.

That's what I managed to do, is that correct? But I got stuck on item b).

Comment: You showed that $\overline{d}(x,y)=0$ when $x=y$, but you didn't show iff (you need to show that if $\overline{d}(x,y)=0$, then $x=y$). 

You can't write $|x-y|$, because $M$ is not necessarily a set of numbers with absolute value. You should replace each $|x-y|$ with $d(x,y)$, and the same for $z$. 

In the triangle inequality, it's not correct to write $\overline{d}(x,z) \leqslant \overline{d}(z,y)+\overline{d}(y,x)$ as the first step. This should be the conclusion. The rest of what you have written there ($|z-y|+|y-x|=|x-z|$) is not correct.

Comment: It's not correct to say that $\overline{d}(x,y)=\min \{0,1\}$ for c. The fact that $d(x,y)\geqslant 0$ doesn't mean you can put zero in the minimum. It is correct that $0\leqslant \min \{d(x,y),1\}\leqslant 1$. 

It is not necessarily true that $d(x,y)$ can take any value greater than $0$. For example, if $M=\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual distance, $d(x,y)$ can only take non-negative integer values. To show that $A$ is not necessarily bounded on $(M,d)$, you can do this with an example. This is basically asking you to show that arbitrary metric spaces don't have to be bounded.